# addChild empty when it should not be

Tags: actionscript-3

Currently im trying to make a moving background.So im calculating how many objects can be on the stage and then adding those objects to 2 **containers** but it seems that it is just adding them to the last container **spriteContainer2**  when i trace with **....numChildren**

so i know what is wrong but .. i dont know why it is doing so. And can someone help me with a solution for this, because im not that familiar with all the methods in flash.(in real world i would get the 1st **container** and make a copy of it and then use it )

```
    var speed:int = 1
var offset:int;
var spriteContainer:Sprite = new Sprite;
var spriteContainer2:Sprite = new Sprite;

var redSqBitmapData:BitmapData = new Tile_1();
var redSqBitmapData2:BitmapData = new Tile_2();
var my_shape:Bitmap = new Bitmap(redSqBitmapData);

my_shape.scaleX  = my_shape.scaleY = stage.stageWidth / my_shape.width
trace(my_shape.height)

var stageH:Number = stage.stageHeight;
var elementH:Number = my_shape.height;
var numberElements:int = Math.ceil(stageH / elementH);
var i:int=0

for( i; i< numberElements; i++){

    var my_shape2 = new Bitmap(redSqBitmapData);
    my_shape2.scaleX  = my_shape2.scaleY = stage.stageWidth / my_shape2.width
    my_shape2.x = 0;
    my_shape2.y = my_shape.height * i
    spriteContainer.addChild(my_shape2)
    spriteContainer2.addChild(my_shape2)

}

addChild(spriteContainer)
trace(spriteContainer.numChildren)
addChild(spriteContainer2)
trace(spriteContainer2.numChildren)

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEveryFrame)
function onEveryFrame(evt:Event):void{

    offset +=  speed;
    spriteContainer.y = offset % spriteContainer.height - spriteContainer.height;
    spriteContainer2.y = spriteContainer.y - spriteContainer2.height

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance of DisplayObject can be only in only one DisplayObjectContainer. Adding the same DisplayObject into new DisplayObjectContainer will remove it from previous Container. Check this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild()

"...If you add a child object that already has a different display object container as a parent, the object is removed from the child list of the other display object container.."

Comment: ouuu i see.Well i did figure that it was something like that cause i commend out the **spriteContainer.addChild(my_shape2)** and set the  **spriteContainer2.y** to 100 and they all shoaled.Yet how do i do it then?

Comment: You can create new Bitmap(redSqBitmapData) for every container.

Comment: you mean like `var my_shape3 = new Bitmap(redSqBitmapData);`
`my_shape3.scaleX  = my_shape3.scaleY = stage.stageWidth / my_shape3.width`
`my_shape3.x = 0;
    my_shape2.y = my_shape.height * i`
and then spriteContainer2.addChild(**my_shape3**) ??? or im not getting what you are telling me

Comment: @AzzyElvul Is it the same way for addElement() in Flex 4, I suppose?